# What will happen when there are two active versions of Entitlement Process?

Tags: casemilestone, entitlements, entitlement-process

I'm just wondering what will happen when there are **two active versions of the same Entitlement Process**.

1. Will it create duplicate milestones?
2. If not then which version will be chosen?
3. Will it pick the version marked as 'Default Version'?

I'm asking because I need to add a new milestone and also edit existing one while not suspending the entire entitlement process for the duration of the update rule.
What steps should I follow?

Answer (score 0):

After you create a new version of an entitlement process, you can choose to apply it to all entitlements assigned to the previous version, or only to new entitlements. When you apply an entitlement process to an entitlement, it also applies the process to that entitlement’s active support records.

USER PERMISSIONS NEEDED

> To create and update entitlement processes:
> Manage Entitlements

NOTE:

> To create multiple versions of entitlement processes, entitlement
> versioning must be enabled in your org. Select Enable Entitlement
> Versioning on the Entitlement Settings page in Setup. When you create
> versions of entitlement processes with the same name, the version
> number and notes help you differentiate between versions. Salesforce
> prevents you from disabling entitlement versioning so you always know
> which version you’re working with.

Refer the [Use a New Version of an Entitlement Process](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.entitlements_process_using_new_versions.htm&type=5)